# Who reviews our edit?

Tags: discussion

I edited a question and see that its pending for peer review. Who will be doing it. AFAIK rep required for closing/editing etc is relaxed now but I don't see the option to Approve/Reject edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rep requirement are reduced, but not zero. From the SharePoint FAQ:

> **500**   Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

500 rep users come into their own pretty quickly. You start out with 101 rep of you associate your account with another site in the Stack Exchange Network. You already have one user with 500 rep and more up and coming. Until then, any of the moderators can approve edits to a post, but the community self-moderation will start taking care of them soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

To look at what needs reviewing, add `/review` to the end of the main site's url. So for the sharepoint site, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/ . I have more than 4k rep on at least one site, and I see no options other than to vote, comment or flag for moderator.

Comment: When you get 10k tools ([1k for betas](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)) you'll get a new tab on `/review` that lets you review suggested edits. You can still do it once you have edit privileges, but there's no centralized list, you just need to stumble across posts with pending edits